# How to thin out a set of incremental files based on Date Modified rules?

Tags: backup, file-management, incremental-backup

**TL/DR:** How can I "thin out" a set of periodically auto-created files, deleting every other file with the same starting name up to ".bak", based on Date/Time Modified but keeping the first and last one from each day?

**The context:** An app I use daily (Pro Tools) auto-creates backup files of the open document ("session file" in Pro Tools) every 5 minutes, maintaining the last 10 backups. It also seems to keep previous days' backups without including them in the "last 10" to overwrite.

I'm left with a 9+ GB folder of auto-backup files for each project, times hundreds of past projects I want to thin out.

The backup file naming scheme is the document name appended with ".bak.###.ptx" (`###` being incremental numbers). However the numbers aren't always consistent for some reason. The document name might slightly change as I save versions of it, which results in a new set of backups.

I'm running macOS Ventura 13.6.3. I've started making a Shortcut (successor to Automator) which receives a folder as the input and so far is outputting a list of files with the .ptx extension. Perhaps all I need is a script to filter and output the files to be deleted?

[image]